# Worldpay Offsite Gateway not redirecting to Customer Order screen on successful transaction

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, worldpay

I am having issues with Craft Commerce and Worldpay's Offsite Payment Gateway.  The way my clients accounts are set up with Worldpay, I cannot use the Worldpay JSON option so this I have to use the offsite method.

Basically, I have it working that its coming through as successful transaction on Worldpay's end - however I get left on the offsite thank you page, it doesn't redirect back to my local craft install.

Is there something that I need to do to trigger this? Because of this the order sits in my Orders under the Active cart tab, it does not fully complete.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this installation is working as it should.  When I uploaded the website to a staging server and tested on it, it worked as expected. 
 Redirecting me back to my Craft website, and showing the Customer Order screen whilst sending out relevant emails.

Not sure if it has been documented anywhere, but seems that this doesn't play ball when working locally.

Comment: It can't return you when working locally since it doesn't know where 'local' is. Your local is different to my local. So where would it send you?